# What services could be used as back-end for a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, server

I have an idea for a mobile app that I would like to make. I am experienced in programming locally on the device, but not so much at making something that has a server in it.
I have (rather hastily) rented a server at HostGator and rented the domain name.
I made a project for university before and did the server-side scripting, but it had flaws, wasn't well polished and took a lot of time. So I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.
I have been searching the internet from morning till night for services that would take the load of server-side from my bac.

---

I'm planning to build an iPhone and an android app that will actually be "wrappers" to my data on the server. I will need user accounts and databases in general. The app will basically connect the users in some way and organize events for them. I saw a lot of names like "Parse" and "Kinvey" but I'm not really sure if that's what I'm looking for or not. Would I need to build an API myself, put it on the server, and wrap the apps around it? Or is there (hopefully) another solution? I'm looking for general guidance and what to research exactly.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are BaaSs (Backend-as-a-Service) and there are plenty to choose from. I highly recommend [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as a starting point as it's pretty easy to work with and pretty fast to get up and running, though there may be a learning curve in grasping how you should define your data in an efficient way. Parse is now defunct and you'll probably still have to wrangle with trying to get it deployed to a server, which may be a daunting task if you don't have experience with that kind of stuff as it's now just an open source project that doesn't give you any server infrastructure to work with out of the box like they use to. Other promising BaaSs is [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/)'s mobile platform which I haven't tried yet.